# Rolling correlation with id and date

Tags: r, date, time-series, correlation

I have some data that has a name, date, and two factors (x,y).  I would like to calculate

```
  dt<-seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), by = "days", length.out = 20)
  df1<-data.frame("ABC",dt,rnorm(20, 0,3),rnorm(20, 2,4) )
      names(df1)<-c("name","date","x","y")
  df2<-data.frame("XYZ",dt,rnorm(20, 2,5),rnorm(20, 3,10) )
      names(df2)<-c("name","date","x","y")
  df<-rbind(df1,df2)
```

I would like to add a column named "Correl" that for each date, takes the correlation of the previous 5 periods.  However, when the name changes, I would like it to give NA's instead.

As you can see below, when the data becomes XYZ instead of ABC, the first 4 periods, the correlation is NA.  When there's 5 data points is when the correlation begins again.

```
  name  date    x   y   Correl
  ABC   1/1/2013    -3.59   -5.13   NA
  ABC   1/2/2013    -8.69   4.22    NA
  ABC   1/3/2013    2.80    -0.59   NA
  ABC   1/4/2013    0.54    5.06    NA
  ABC   1/5/2013    1.13    3.49    -0.03
  ABC   1/6/2013    0.52    5.16    -0.38
  ABC   1/7/2013    -0.24   -5.40   0.08
  ABC   1/8/2013    3.26    -2.75   -0.16
  ABC   1/9/2013    1.33    5.94    -0.04
  ABC   1/10/2013   2.24    1.14    -0.01
  ABC   1/11/2013   0.01    9.87    -0.24
  ABC   1/12/2013   2.29    1.28    -0.99
  ABC   1/13/2013   1.03    -6.30   -0.41
  ABC   1/14/2013   0.62    4.82    -0.47
  ABC   1/15/2013   1.08    -1.17   -0.50
  ABC   1/16/2013   2.43    8.86    0.45
  ABC   1/17/2013   -3.43   9.38    -0.35
  ABC   1/18/2013   -5.73   7.59    -0.38
  ABC   1/19/2013   1.77    3.13    -0.44
  ABC   1/20/2013   -0.97   -0.77   -0.24
  XYZ   1/1/2013    2.12    10.22   NA
  XYZ   1/2/2013    -0.81   0.22    NA
  XYZ   1/3/2013    -1.55   -2.25   NA
  XYZ   1/4/2013    -4.53   3.63    NA
  XYZ   1/5/2013    2.95    -1.51   0.13
  XYZ   1/6/2013    6.76    24.16   0.69
  XYZ   1/7/2013    3.33    7.31    0.66
  XYZ   1/8/2013    -1.47   -4.23   0.67
  XYZ   1/9/2013    3.89    -0.43   0.81
  XYZ   1/10/2013   5.63    17.95   0.86
  XYZ   1/11/2013   3.29    -7.09   0.63
  XYZ   1/12/2013   6.03    -9.03   0.29
  XYZ   1/13/2013   -5.63   6.96    -0.19
  XYZ   1/14/2013   1.70    13.59   -0.18
  XYZ   1/15/2013   -1.19   -16.79  -0.29
  XYZ   1/16/2013   4.76    4.91    -0.11
  XYZ   1/17/2013   9.02    25.16   0.57
  XYZ   1/18/2013   4.56    6.48    0.84
  XYZ   1/19/2013   5.30    11.81   0.99
  XYZ   1/20/2013   -0.60   3.38    0.84
```

UPDATE: I have tried all of your suggestions and have run into problems using the actual data.  I have attached a subset of the data below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6k4xhwuinlu0p1f/TEST_SUBSET.csv?dl=0

I cannot get this to work.  I've tried removing the NA's, renaming the rows, reading the data in differently, formatting the date differently.  Nothing is working for me.  Can you see if what you are running is working for this dataset?  Thank you very much folks!

Comment: for (n in unique(df$name))
           {
           df1<-df[df$name==n,]
           correl<-cor(df1$x,df1$y)
           assign(paste0(n),data.frame(n,correl))
         }  I tried using a for loop to go through the list of names and then subsetting the table.  This would be somewhat OK, but I still dont' know how to do the rolling part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little late to the party, but the below is a pretty compact solution with `dplyr` and `rollapply` from (`zoo` package).

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

  dt<-seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), by = "days", length.out = 20)
  df1<-data.frame("ABC",dt,rnorm(20, 0,3),rnorm(20, 2,4) )
      names(df1)<-c("name","date","x","y")
  df2<-data.frame("XYZ",dt,rnorm(20, 2,5),rnorm(20, 3,10) )
      names(df2)<-c("name","date","x","y")
  df<-rbind(df1,df2)


df<-df %>%
  group_by(name)%>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  do({
    correl <- rollapply(.[-(1:2)],width = 5, function(a) cor(a[,1],a[,2]), by.column = FALSE, align = "right", fill = NA)
    data.frame(., correl)
  })
```

which returns...

```
> df
Source: local data frame [40 x 5]
Groups: name

   name       date           x          y      correl
1   ABC 2013-01-01 -0.61707785 -0.7299461          NA
2   ABC 2013-01-02  1.35353618  9.1314743          NA
3   ABC 2013-01-03  2.60815932  0.2511828          NA
4   ABC 2013-01-04 -2.89619789 -1.2586655          NA
5   ABC 2013-01-05  2.23750886  4.6616034  0.52013407
6   ABC 2013-01-06 -1.97573999  3.6800832  0.37575664
7   ABC 2013-01-07  1.70360813  2.2621718  0.32390612
8   ABC 2013-01-08  0.02017797  2.5088032  0.64020507
9   ABC 2013-01-09  0.96263256  1.6711756 -0.00557611
10  ABC 2013-01-10 -0.62400803  5.2011656 -0.66040650
..  ...        ...         ...        ...         ...
```

checking that the other group responds correctly...

```
> df %>%
+   filter(name=="XYZ")
Source: local data frame [20 x 5]
Groups: name

   name       date          x          y     correl
1   XYZ 2013-01-01  3.4199729  5.0866361         NA
2   XYZ 2013-01-02  4.7326297 -5.4613465         NA
3   XYZ 2013-01-03  3.8983329 11.1635903         NA
4   XYZ 2013-01-04  1.5235936  3.9077184         NA
5   XYZ 2013-01-05 -5.4885373  7.8961020 -0.3755766
6   XYZ 2013-01-06  0.2311371  2.0157046 -0.3754510
7   XYZ 2013-01-07  2.6903306 -3.2940181 -0.1808097
8   XYZ 2013-01-08 -0.2584268  3.6047800 -0.8457930
9   XYZ 2013-01-09 -0.2897795  2.1029431 -0.9526992
10  XYZ 2013-01-10  5.9571558 18.5810947  0.7025559
11  XYZ 2013-01-11 -7.5250647 -8.0858699  0.7949917
12  XYZ 2013-01-12  2.8438336 -8.4072829  0.6563161
13  XYZ 2013-01-13  7.2295030 -0.1236801  0.5383666
14  XYZ 2013-01-14 -0.7579570 -0.2830291  0.5542751
15  XYZ 2013-01-15  4.3116507 -6.5291051  0.3894343
16  XYZ 2013-01-16  1.4334510  0.5957465 -0.1480032
17  XYZ 2013-01-17 -2.6444881  6.1261976 -0.6183805
18  XYZ 2013-01-18  0.8517223  0.5587499 -0.9243050
19  XYZ 2013-01-19  6.2140131 -3.0944259 -0.8939475
20  XYZ 2013-01-20 11.2871086 -0.1187153 -0.6845300
```

Hope this helps!

### FOLLOW UP

---

I just ran the following on your actual data set:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
import <- read.csv("TEST_SUBSET.CSV", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(head(import))

import_df<-import %>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  arrange(asof_dt) %>%
  do({
    correl <- rollapply(.[-(1:2)],width = 5, function(a) cor(a[,1],a[,2]), by.column = FALSE, align = "right", fill = NA)
    data.frame(., correl)
  })
import_df
```

and received the following:

```
> import_df
Source: local data frame [15,365 x 5]
Groups: id

       id   asof_dt            x            y     correl
1  DC1123 1/10/1990 -0.003773632           NA         NA
2  DC1123 1/10/1991  0.014034992           NA         NA
3  DC1123 1/10/1992 -0.004109765           NA         NA
4  DC1123 1/10/1994  0.006369326  0.012176085         NA
5  DC1123 1/10/1995  0.014900600  0.001241080         NA
6  DC1123 1/10/1996  0.005763689 -0.013112491         NA
7  DC1123 1/10/1997  0.006949765  0.010737034         NA
8  DC1123 1/10/2000  0.044052805  0.003346296 0.02724175
9  DC1123 1/10/2001  0.009452785  0.017582638 0.01362101
10 DC1123 1/10/2002 -0.018876970  0.004346372 0.01343657
..    ...       ...          ...          ...        ...
```

so it feels like its working.
The (cor) function is only going to return data when it has 5 input points, which doesn't happen until row 8.

Comment: Hello Colemand.  I am receiving this error when I copy and paste it " Error: expecting a single value"  thank you!

Comment: I've re-run the code in clean r sessions and it seems to work fine.  Added the output from your actual data as well.  Not sure if your dplyr package is older, but I know at one point they changed the syntax for the `do()` function.  Might be worth checking on that if you're still getting errors?

Comment: Thanks Colemand77.  Now it works.  However, when I try to run my entire data set, I get "Error in seq.default(start.at, NROW(data), by = by) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument"  I am thinking it's my dataset, but I cannot post it as it's confidential.  Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this more effectively?  thank you.

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question, as this one has been answered (by several people) for all the use cases provided.  My gut is that it is your data set, but there is literally nothing anyone can do to fix that if it is confidential.  My suggestion is to sub-set the data and run the function on the groups to find out where the inconsistent data is.

Comment: colemand77, agreed.  I found the issue - I tried increasing the size of the window.  The window size was larger than the total number of records for some of the initial records.  I subsetted the ones that didn't have enough records out of it and it's working now.  Appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Comment: Awesome... Glad you ground it out.  Good to know that's the error thrown in that case.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me on this colemand77.  I am a newbie in R and a long time data analyst soooo...like a kid who has a lot to say but can't find his words...

Answer (score 2):

Apply `ave` to the row indexes of `df` to process by name and use `rollapplyr` to perform the rolling computations.  Note that `i` is a vector of indexes:

```
library(zoo)

corx <- function(x) cor(x[, 1], x[, 2])
df$Correl <- ave(1:nrow(df), df$name, FUN = function(i) 
      rollapplyr(df[i, c("x", "y")], 5, corx, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA))
```

**Update** Changed `rollapply` to `rollapplyr` to be consistent with the output shown in the question.  If you want centred correlations change it back to `rollapply`.

Comment: When I put my data into this function, I get ` Error in seq.default(start.at, NROW(data), by = by) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In `$.data.frame`(df3, name) : Name partially matched in data frame`  i tried removing the existing NA's, renaming the rows, putting it all into the same data frame, and it still is not working.  Do you know what that error is?  Thank you

Comment: The `name` column shown in the question is actually `id` in your csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a a solution using base R, note that it requires that the data set be sorted by `name` and `date`, in that order.

```
dt<-seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), by = "days", length.out = 20)
df1<-data.frame("ABC",dt,rnorm(20, 0,3),rnorm(20, 2,4) )
names(df1)<-c("name","date","x","y")
df2<-data.frame("XYZ",dt,rnorm(20, 2,5),rnorm(20, 3,10) )
names(df2)<-c("name","date","x","y")
df<-rbind(df1,df2)

rollcorr = function(df, lag = 4) {
  out = numeric(nrow(df) - lag)
  for( i in seq_along(out) ) {
    window = i:(i+lag)
    out[i] = cor(df$x[window], df$y[window])
  }
  out <- c(rep(NA, lag), out)
  return(out)
}

df$Correl <- do.call(c, by(df[, -1], df[, 1], rollcorr))
```

Comment: This worked well when I did some unit testing.  However, when I tried to do the entire data set, which is around 5 million rows, I get the following error: "Error in numeric(nrow(df) - lag) : invalid 'length' argument"  Do you have any ideas how I can troubleshoot or find where it's breaking?